# Java Accessing subclasses methods/variables from abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

This code is not mine and i need to add some improvements to it, but i'm stuck in this problem.

I have an abstract class "CallNode" and a lot of subclasses, one of them is "Call". The "Checker" class is intercepting missed calls, but return them as CallNode. My problem is that i need to get the id of this call, but i can't access it by CallNode.

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

I let you the code, so that you can better understand the problem:

```
public abstract class CallNode {
    public abstract CallNode hasMissingCall();
}

public class Call extends CallNode {
    public int id;

    // Simplification of method
    public CallNode hasMissingCall() {  
        if (true)
            return this;
        // ...
    }
}

public class Checker{
    private static CallNode rootExpected;

    CallNode missing = rootExpected.hasMissingCall();

    System.out.println( missing.id ); // THE PROBLEM!!!
}
```

Thank's in advance!!!

Comment: `public abstract CallNode hasMissingCall();`, sounds like it should return a boolean instead. Really bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a template method returning the id in the abstract class:

```
public abstract class CallNode {
    public abstract CallNode hasMissingCall();

    public abstract int getId();
}
```

let subclass implement it:

```
public class Call extends CallNode {
    public int id;

    // Simplification of method
    public CallNode hasMissingCall() {  
        if (true)
            return this;
        // ...
    }
    public int getId()
    {
         return this.id;
    }
}
```

That's an option. Personally I'll move the id field upward in the CallNode class, since I think it's supposed to be unique and shared by all subclasses.

Comment: Thank's Heisenbug. I was trying to avoid changes in a lot of classes, but it's really needed! I will move the "id" field to "CallNode" and create an abstract "getID()".

Comment: Plus one for the last suggestion, and the name Heisenbug.

Answer (score 2):

You should `never directly access your fields`.

In general the `fields` should be declared `private` and you should have `public accessor` methods to access them.

If you can modify your classes, then add a method `getId()` in both `abstract CallNode` class and `Call` class. And in Call class have this method return your `this.id`. This will do the job for you.

So, add this method to your `Call` class: -

```
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Let this method be `abstract` in your `Abstract` class.

```
public abstract class CallNode {
    public abstract CallNode hasMissingCall();
    public abstract int getId();
}
```

And invoke it using : -

```
missing.getId();
```

This will call the `getId()` of your `Call` class.

> This code is not mine and i need to add some improvements to it,

**PS: -** One improvement you really need to add is, change the `hasMissingCall` to `getMissingCall` as it is returning you a `missed call`. Always follow `naming conventions` in your code.
**Remember**, you don't write code for yourself, but you write them for others to use and maintain.

Comment: Thank's for the tips, Rohit. I have all my fields declared as "private", the code i've presented is a simplification of the real one so that the problem could be faster identified. I'll use the solution you propose. About the methods nomenclature, i admit that is not the best, but it isn't my code. Once again, thank's for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast down to `Call`:

```
System.out.println( ((Call) missing).id );
```

That's if you can't change the other classes, and if you know `missing` will be an instance of `Call`.

Comment: Thank you, Vlad! But i'm verifying by now that i can't guarantee "missing" will be an instance of "Call", it can be a instance of another subclass of "CallNode".

Answer (score 0):

You can specify absract method getId() in CallNode and implement it in children. Then you an access it in your Checker.

```
public abstract class CallNode {
    public abstract CallNode hasMissingCall();
    public abstract int getId();
}

public class Checker{
    private static CallNode rootExpected;

    CallNode missing = rootExpected.hasMissingCall();

    System.out.println( missing.getId() );
}

public class Call extends CallNode {
    public int id; // better set private modifier
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Anton. I'll use this approach.